# Join Query fired error result set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table named `tbl_documents`, that records some details of  a document like `doc_no`, `branch_no`, `doc_name`, `date` etc.

I included following line inside my function to get all the fields of `tbl_documents` table.

```
...

$this->db->select('*')
->from('tbl_documents')         
->where('status', 1, '', FALSE);

...
```

The function is working fine & generated the correct output. But the `branch_no` in `tbl_documents` table is related with `branch_no` in `tbl_branch` table. It is also included another field `branch_names` like : Admin, Accounts, IT etc.

If I used the following code to get branch names for the desired out put, it fired an error.

```
 $this->db->select('*')
 ->from('tbl_documents')
 ->join('tbl_branch', 'tbl_branch.branch_id=tbl_documents.branch_id', 'left')
 ->where('status', 1, '', FALSE);
```

What may be wrong? Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this may help you:

```
    $this->db->select('*')
     ->from('tbl_documents')
     ->join('tbl_branch', 'tbl_branch.branch_id=tbl_documents.branch_id', 'left')
     ->where('status', 1, '', FALSE);
     return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way. i hope it will help you:

```
$this->db->select('tbl_documents.*,fields_name_which_you_want_get');
$this->db->->join('tbl_branch', 'tbl_branch.branch_id=tbl_documents.branch_id', 'left');
return $this->db->where('status', 1, '', FALSE)->get('tbl_documents')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it would solve your problem.

```
 $this->db->select('tbl_branch.*,tbl_documents.*')
 ->from('tbl_documents')
 ->join('tbl_branch', 'tbl_branch.branch_id=tbl_documents.branch_id', 'left')
 ->where('status', 1, '', FALSE)->result_array();;
```